# Insert into table from a temp table without identity column ?

Tags: sql, temp-tables

I need to insert into table with same column in temp table. without identity column of table which am inserting.
Remaining columns of inserting table is contained in temp table.

Comment: `Dynamic Query` plus `Information_Schema.Columns`

Comment: What are you asking? Do you already have a temp table and don't know how to write the INSERT statement or do you want to create the temp table but don't want to write the entire CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: @Fireblade or a SELECT INTO.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - Looks like he already have a temp table and he want to pull data from another table except the identity column data.

Comment: Then a plain old INSERT SELECT with the relevant fields is OK. The OP should *really* clarify what is asked

Comment: I guess we should wait for him to enlighten us

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: He want´s to insert records from a table that doesnt contain the primary key / identity columns of the target table, so he needs to add sql code to generate primary key values "on the fly" / manually.

Comment: I believe that @Udontknow is correct, but to identify a solution, we need to know the database the OP is using.  Bharatkmr - Please add a tag to the question to identify the database and version you are using (like Oracle11, SQLServer2008, etc...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be able to generate primary key values on your own. With IBM DB2, I am using sequences to get those values. It would be good to know which RDBMS you are using.

A statement matching your needs could look like that:

```
INSERT INTO MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE 
select (NEXTVAL FOR MYSCHEMA.ID_SEQUENCE) as ID, T.*
from MYSCHEMA.MYTEMPTABLE T
```